# Add jQuery draggable object in c# codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have been able to create a site using jQuery to create droppable and draggable objects.
I now have a new request to load a number of draggable objects using c# code.

I can add the objects but they are not draggable. Using the dev tools (F12) for the browser, i am able to inspect objects manually added and the ones that were loaded through the c# script. The attributes are similar.

However, the ones loaded with the script are not draggable. Can somebody shed some light on what i may have missed here?

Below is my code.

```
                        Panel pnlContainer = new Panel();
                    pnlContainer.ID = string.Format("pnlContainer_{0}_{1}", field.PageNumber, fieldIdx);
                    //Set the new ID for the field to the internal identifier
                    field.InternalFieldIdentifier = pnlContainer.ID;

                    pnlContainer.CssClass = "draggableItem ui-draggable dropped ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle";
                    pnlContainer.Attributes.Add("style", "top:" + calculated_top + "px; left: " + field.Left + "px");
                    pnlContainer.Attributes.Add("fieldname", string.Format("pnlContainer_{0}_{1}", field.PageNumber, fieldIdx));
                    pnlContainer.Attributes.Add("fieldtype", "textbox");                        

                    pnlContainer.Height = Unit.Pixel((int)field.Height);
                    pnlContainer.Width = Unit.Pixel((int)field.Width);                        

                    Label lblHandle = new Label();                        
                    lblHandle.CssClass = "draghandle";
                    lblHandle.Text = "::";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(lblHandle);

                    Label lblContent = new Label();                        
                    lblContent.CssClass = "draggableItemContentText";
                    //lblContent.CssClass = "dropped";
                    lblContent.Text = "Text Box";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(lblContent);

                    //=======================================
                    //Used for directional resizing purposes
                    //=======================================
                    Panel pnlResize_n = new Panel();                        
                    pnlResize_n.CssClass = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n";
                    pnlResize_n.Attributes.Add("style", "z-index: 90;");
                    //lblContent.Text = "Text Box";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(pnlResize_n);

                    Panel lblResize_e = new Panel();                        
                    lblResize_e.CssClass = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e";
                    lblResize_e.Attributes.Add("style", "z-index: 90;");
                    //lblContent.Text = "Text Box";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(lblResize_e);

                    Panel lblResize_w = new Panel();                        
                    lblResize_w.CssClass = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w";
                    lblResize_w.Attributes.Add("style", "z-index: 90;");
                    //lblContent.Text = "Text Box";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(lblResize_w);

                    Panel lblResize_s = new Panel();                        
                    lblResize_s.CssClass = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s";
                    lblResize_s.Attributes.Add("style", "z-index: 90;");
                    //lblContent.Text = "Text Box";
                    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(lblResize_s);                        

                    pnlPdfPage.Controls.Add(pnlContainer);
```

Below is the source view of the object after the c# code was executed.

```
<div id="rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlContainer_1_1" class="draggableItem ui-draggable dropped ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" fieldname="pnlContainer_1_1" fieldtype="textbox" style="height:18px;width:197px;top:155px; left: 106px">
    <span class="draghandle">::</span><span class="draggableItemContentText">Text Box</span>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;">

    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;">

    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;">

    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;">

    </div>
```

Manual added object

```
    <div id="txtbx_0" class="draggableItem ui-draggable dropped ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" page="1" fieldtype="textbox" fieldname="txtbx_0" style="top: 154px; left: 124px; width: 277px;">                
        <span class="draghandle">::</span>
        <span class="draggableItemContentText">Text Box</span>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the source of the manual object that worked?

Comment: Yes, please see the area marked "Manual added object"

Comment: I sure don't see anything obvious.  Could it have something on top of it (z-index) that isn't draggable?

Comment: I'm not sure, i will look into it.

It just hit me that even though i have added the objects, i still need to make them draggable through jQuery. 
This would mean that when the objects are added in the backend, in this case c#, i would then have to loop through each object through jQuery and add the draggable property to it. What do you think?

Comment: I was assuming that since the one was working and had the same class that you were applying the draggable function to the class, so yes, that might be it.

Comment: I have figured it out. i will post the code here so that anybody tracking this post can see it. I was loading the objects in the codebehind without running the script that makes them draggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code needs to run on the client side after the objects have been added in the code behind

```
        $(function () {
        //Make element draggable
        $(".draggableItem").draggable({
            //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
            helper: function () {
                return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({
                    'zIndex': 5
                });
            },
            revert: "invalid",
            cursor: 'move',
            containment: '#pdfViewer'
        });

        $(".existingFieldItem").each(function () {
            var droppedObject = $(this).parent()[0];
            var field_type = $(this).attr("fieldtype");
            applyDroppedAttributes($(this), droppedObject, field_type);
        });

        //Make element droppable
        $(".droppablePage").droppable({
            accept: '.draggableItem, .existingFieldItem'
          });
     });
```